# "Not a function" javascript error (jquery floatingbox plugin)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, floating

I always was wondering why the floatingbox plugin was not able to put a div container at the bottom right of my page.
http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/Jquery-Floating-Box-Plugin/
Today I checked my site with firebug, and found this error:

> $("#thediv").floating is not a
> function
>
> ON LINE: $("#thediv").floating({targetX:"right",
> targetY:"bottom"});

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.floatingbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(
        function(){
            jQuery("#thediv").floating({targetX:"right", targetY:"bottom"});
        }
    );
</script>
```

The floating function is created like this in the plugin:

```
jQuery.fn.floating = function(options)
{
    return jQuery(this).each(

        function(i)
        {
            var nextIndex = 0;
            for(var index in funcFloating)
            {
                nextIndex = parseInt(index);
            }
            funcFloating[nextIndex + 1] = {};
            funcFloating[nextIndex + 1].box = this;
            funcFloating[nextIndex + 1].obj = new floatingBox(this, options, (nextIndex + 1));
            funcFloating[nextIndex + 1].func = function(){ funcFloating[nextIndex + 1].obj.doFloat(); };
            if (document.layers)
            {
                funcFloating[nextIndex + 1].obj.init();
            }else
            {

                funcFloating[nextIndex + 1].obj.init();
                funcFloating[nextIndex + 1].obj.initSecondary();
            }

        }
    );
};
```

What can I do to fix this?
When looking at the source code on the plugin's example page, I see the same code is used as on my own page.

If this was a conflict error of some sorts, wouldn't the first use of "$" (in "$(document)") already trigger an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, are you sure that the `floating()` function has been defined on `$.fn`, the jQuery object prototype?

1. Make sure that you've properly included the floatingbox js file
2. Make sure it's after the jquery include so the `$` object exists at the time the plugin tries to extend the prototype.

Edit: According to the code sample, it is being included in the right order. Do you have a link so we can see the problem?

Comment: The function was defined correctly, I believe. I just took the code from the plugins page. I will add it to the above post. Sorry, I cannot post a link.

Comment: From the demo page, it looks like it's declaring the function on the prototype fine. Are you using any other JS libraries that use `$`? If so, you should use `jQuery.noConflict();` and replace `$("#thediv")` with `jQuery("#thediv")`

Comment: I will try that. There are other libraries on the page (from yahoo). As far as I understand, the noConflict call will switch jQuery over for the rest of the page? Is there a way to only make it use the noConflict for this single function call?

Comment: Okay, well, it's not working anyway. I put noConflict(); in front of the documentready call above and switched the $-signs to jQuery. The error is still the same: "jQuery("#thediv").floating is not a function".

Comment: Hard to offer any more ideas without seeing the actual page. If you can prepare a sample page that exhibits the problem and upload it somewhere, that would be helpful.

Comment: I found the problem: jquery.js was embedded twice in the page.

Answer (score 0):

[This plugin?](http://www.marcelljusztin.com/stuff/jquery-floating-box/floating-box-jquery.html)  If so, take a look at the source of that page for an example.  One:

```
$('#moving_box1').floatingBox({
    scale : 0.3,
    blur : true,
    isText : false,
    xOffset : 235,
    yOffset: 185,
});
```

Comment: Sorry, no, that's not the one I am using. I have updated the original post with the plugin's url. It's more of a general question, too, because there must be something wrong with the way I am calling the floating function.